# When change lua table value?

Tags: list, hash, lua, lua-table

Three loops but different results, why? (in lua 5.1)

**1.**

```
local a = {{b=5}, {b=4}}
for k,v in ipairs(a) do
   v.b = v.b + 1
end
```

**2.**

```
local a = {["b"]=5, ["bb"]=4}
for k,v in pairs(a) do
   v = v + 1
end
```

**3.**

```
local a = {5, 4}
for k,v in ipairs(a) do
   v = v + 1
end
```

- **1** truly add 1 to all elements in table a, but **2**&**3** change nothing. **why?**
- I use **chunkspy** to see the op code of these three blocks found that in first block it has settable op after alter the value in table a, but block **2**or**3** has not. Block **2**&**3** just do **add        5   5   261  ; 1** (means add 1 to register 5 but not save the value to table), why this happen?

Comment: Because `v` is a simple local variable existing inside the loop.  Modifying `v` itself does not modify data in your table.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here, is that `v` in a `k,v` pair, is a reference to the value, not the key.

This means, that `v=` just modifies the local variable `v` and doesn't affect the table itself. You could, instead do `a[k]=v+1`, which carries the intended result for 2 and 3.

In the first case however, `v` is a reference to a table. And in lua, Modifying a table, or any reference to that table, is done to all references to the table. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value) question contains some helpful information on the topic of References Vs Values.

Comment: thx! i got it, pairs and ipair just functions return ref to the table value, right?

Comment: Yes, as stated in the answer. Once again, if you want to modify the table, `k` holds the key that returned that value, so `a[k] = something` will set that value for you, although `v` will not update.

Comment: @jammyWolf It's good practice to accept the answer that solved your problem.